# Is there a way to delete a BigQuery view when its table gets deleted?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Can I get notified when the bigquery table is deleted to delete the related view(s)?

Comment: It could be a great feature of recommender toolbox. Open a feature request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information from the logs. You can create a [Stackdriver sink to Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs#pubsub-overview) with the following filter :

```
protoPayload.serviceName="bigquery.googleapis.com"
protoPayload.methodName="google.cloud.bigquery.v2.TableService.DeleteTable"
```

to retrieve logs representing tables deletions. You can then create a Cloud Function or a Cloud Run reacting on these events, and delete the related views or whatever you want to do.

Comment: In the same way, you can catch the errors when the view run and don't find the deleted table.

Comment: Ended up using your suggestion. it is now called cloud logging logs router

Comment: @norbjd is there a way to scan all bq projects for table deletion and not only the ones of the project inside which we created the sink?

Comment: @hzitoun yes, you can create a sink on the whole organization !